# Цикл for в цикле for. Как оно считает?

Tags: javascript

```js
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    sum = i + j
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Ответ 7.
Но почему я здесь вижу 6? Цикл с j будет считать трижды. То есть

```
1) 0 + 0 = 0
2) 1 + 1 = 2 (sum)
3) 2(sum) + 2 + 2 = 6
```

Подскажите где еще 1 затерялась?

Comment: Ответ 7, последняя итерация: 2 + 5, 7

Comment: Первый раз оно считает по нулям. Сумма = 0. Второй раз по еденичке - сумма =2. Третий раз(последний) сумма уже 2, и оно берет 2 з i-цикла , 2-j цикла. В итоге 6. @entithat

Comment: Мне достаточно того, что я вижу `sum = i + j`, а значит, что последнее значение, которое туда запишется будет 2 + 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте вывод в каждой итерации и посмотрите, что на самом деле проихсодит:

```js
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    sum = i + j
    console.log(`sum = ${i} + ${j}`)
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Спасибо, на практике понял, что к чему

Answer (score 3):

Первый шаг внешнего цикла i = 0.

Переход к внутреннему циклу. Внутренний цикл отработает 6 шагов (j от 0 до 5)

Второй шаг внешнего цикла i = 1.

Переход к внутреннему циклу. Внутренний цикл отработает 6 шагов (j от 0 до 5)

Третий шаг внешнего цикла i = 2.

Переход к внутреннему циклу. Внутренний цикл отработает 6 шагов (j от 0 до 5)

Выход из внешнего цикла.

`sum = i + j` - каждый раз суммируются значения счетчиков, но суммы не сохраняются, не дополняются. В итоге в консоль будет выведена сумма последних значений счетчиков

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я думал, что они все суммируются...

Comment: `sum = sum + i + j` - вот так суммируются все суммы пар (ответ - 63)